# Displaying Silverlight apps in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I am looking for the Silverlight equivalent of the age-old Flash "loadMovie" function.

I know it is possible to load code dynamically in Silverlight from DLLs. But this assumes there is a pre-arranged contract between the host and the DLL. I am looking for a way to display Silverlight content within a running Silverlight application, without either having to know too much about eachother.

Answer (score 1):

This one may be what you are looking for.

http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2009/05/17/a-smaller-xap-preloader-for-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Prism sounds like it might be what you're looking for.  It's a modularity framework that lets you load up .xap files in a decoupled way and inject that code into a region of your application.  The module you're loading doesn't need to know anything about what it's loading and the loaded module doesn't need to know anything more than just the name of the region it goes into (and maybe not even that if there's a way around the methods I generally use).

There's a good overview series of videos on channel 9 [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-1-Taking-Sketched-Code-Towards-Unity/), as well as a lot of good Q&A that goes on around the framework here on StackOverflow.  Hope that helps.